# Python classes and lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem is the following: I have a text with 100 lines, each line contains the family- name, the given-name and one room in the form "family-name, Given-name room" the room contained by 3 elements "building,floor,office" like "A.15.10" so a complete line will be

```
   "name, name A.15.10"
```

I want to make a class Room with attributes building, floor,office and store room like "A.15.10". The a class with attributes familyname, givenname, room. I want to load all the information from this file to an array of familyname, givenname, room and print it out. What i did until now without classes.

```
   file=open('file.txt','r')
   data=file.readlines()
   k=len(data)
   c=list(range(k))
   for i in range(k):
       c=data.split()
   for i in range(k):
       d=c[i][2].split('.')
```

now the element c[i][0] is the family-name c[i][1] the given-name and c[i][3] the room. After i split again the element c[i][3] to have the building the floor and the room. How can i have all these by classes. Sorry if i didn't explain the problem well.

Comment: Note that you should really use [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for opening files in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an refactoring of your code which uses classes. Without a little more detail on the expected output it is hard to tell if this will completely suffice for your needs.

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, building, floor, office):
        self.building = building
        self.floor = floor
        self.office = office 

class Entry:
    def __init__(self, lastname, firstname, room):
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.room = room 

entries = []
file=open('file.txt','r')
for line in file.readlines():
    lastname, remaining = line.split(', ')
    firstname, remaining = remaining.split(' ')
    building, floor, office = remaining.split('.')
    room = Room(building, floor, office)
    entry = Entry(lastname, firstname, room)
    entries.append(entry)
file.close()
```

Comment: Here if the room in the Entry must be take from the class Room we take it as self.__Room__=room?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are asking.
You can access Room attributes from the entry by using `entry.room.building` or `entry.room.floor` or `entry.room.office`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using classes, namedtuples might be a simpler alternatives. You can also use regular expressions to parse the file in one step:

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools   import starmap

Entry    = namedtuple('Entry', ['familyname', 'givenname', 'building', 'floor', 'office'])
entry_re = re.compile(r'([^,]*), (.*) ([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)\n')

with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    entries = starmap(Entry, entry_re.findall(f.read()))

for entry in entries:
    print('familyname:', entry.familyname)
    print('givenname:', entry.givenname)
    print('building:', entry.building)
    print('floor:', entry.floor)
    print('office:', entry.office)

# Output:
# familyname: name
# givenname: name
# building: A
# floor: 15
# office: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class Room with all the required attributes. For the constructor, you have a few options.

1) Create a constructor which takes all the fields.

2) Create a constructor which takes one line from the file as a string and the constructor splits and extracts the fields.

Comments about the code you sent:

```
   file=open('file.txt','r')
   data=file.readlines()
   k=len(data)
   c=list(range(k)) # You are never using c after assignment. 

   for i in range(k):
       c=data.split() # You would want to split data[i] and not data
   for i in range(k):
       d=c[i][2].split('.') # This can go in the previous loop with 
                            # d = c[2].split('.')
```

Comment: In 3.x, range returns a generator.

Answer (score 0):

you could use re to parse the file.

```
 finder = re.compile( r"""
                    (?P<last>\w+),\s+        # Last name 
                    (?P<first>\w+)\s+        # First Name 
                    (?P<building>[A-D]).     # Building Letter
                    (?P<floor>\d+).          # Floor number 
                    (?P<room>\d+)            # Room Number
                    """, re.VERBOSE )

for line in open( "room_names.txt", 'r' ):
    matches = finder.match( line )
    print( matches.group( 'last', 'first' ) )
    print( matches.group( 'building' ,'floor','room') )
```

Just a little too slow on my re skills @Trevor ;)